# Harmonic oscillators in fluids and driven oscllations

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, harmonic-oscillator, spring, oscillators

If given a normal spring/mass system and letting the mass oscillate in a fluid say water, would it be possible for the motion of the fluid, if the fluid is moving to create a driven oscillation and form resonance?

Comment: I don't know about a mass on a spring, but the entire field of aeroelasticity is devoted to studying fluid driven oscillations in mechanical components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. There is typically a situation in which viscous effects generates vortex shedding. The vortex system creates a pressure difference on the surface of the mass, this pressure difference generates a net time varying force that acts on the mass. Then, if vortex shedding occurs at a frequency close to the natural frequency of the mass-spring system, a resonance-like behavior can be expected. In order to understand better the subject you can read about flutter and galloping oscillations.

Note that for the case of dense fluids there is an "added mass" effect that changes the apparent mass of the system; therefore, resonance does not occur exactly at the natural frequency of the "dry" system.

Note also that in some cases frictional forces, resulting from the viscous shear stresses, can be large; they play a damping-like role on the system response.